# How to display JSON nested data in Angular Grid

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-grid

I am working on Angular 5 application and I got class with following data structure, that I need to display in template, possibly using Angular Kendo UI Grid if not then sample to display in  format

I got following class data in json

```
export class MyClass{
ConsultationId: string;
ResponseType: {
    id: string;
    Name:string;
};
TotalResponses: string;
TotalNewResponses:string;
TotalReviewResponses:string;
TotalCompletedResponses:string;
responsesAbstract: {
    ResponseId: string;
    ConsultationId: string;
    ResponseTypeId:string;
    RespondentId:string;
    ResponseCurrentStatus:string
}

}
```

### screen shot of json data

[image]

In attempt to print ResponseType Name by {{MyClass.ResponseType.Name}} but Angular didn't recognise it

Comment: Do you have an instance in your component like `myClass: MyClass;`? Then you only have to call `{{myClass.ResponseType.Name}}` in your HTML

Comment: i have update json out screen shot in my question, and no I don't have myClass:MyClass,

Comment: are you sure about this case of you properties ?

Comment: yes, I am sure..

Comment: Class has ResponseType property but in object its responseType iin camel case !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to update you class properties based on your data

```
export class MyClass {
  consultationId: string;
  responseType: {
    id: string;
    name: string;
  };
  totalResponses: string;
  totalNewResponses: string;
  totalReviewResponses: string;
  totalCompletedResponses: string;
  responsesAbstract: {
    responseId: string;
    consultationId: string;
    responseTypeId: string;
    respondentId: string;
    responseCurrentStatus: string;
  };
}
```

and in component

```
class Component {
  items: MyClass[] = [];

  assign(data) {
    this.items = data;
  }
}
```